# Why Nuxt 3 Api return HTML content, instead of JSON?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

I have a nuxt 3 app and uses ssr (API). Main page and some other pages are working correctly but some complicated pages are not loading correctly. Normally, API request does not need to be shown on network request but I can see it. Also, normal API respond JSON but for some pages, API respond HTML content.

What is wrong here?

```
const {data: service} = await useFetch("/api/service-detail?slug=" + useRoute().params.slug);
```

Server API Request another server:

```
import {getRequestURL} from "h3";

export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
    var requestUrl = String(getRequestURL(event));
    var slug = requestUrl.split('=')[1];

    return $fetch('https://backend-url.example/api/example-endpoint/' + slug);
});
```

Nuxt Config :

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    buildModules: ['@nuxt/http', '@nuxt/http-security'],
    postcss: {
        plugins: {
            tailwindcss: {},
            autoprefixer: {}
        }
    },
    modules: ['nuxt-schema-org'],
    vite: {
        css: {
            preprocessorOptions: {
                sass: {
                    additionalData: '@import "@/assets/styles/_variables.sass"'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```